# How to get text from Datagridview in VB.net and insert it to Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

What is the correct way on doing this, as when i tried this code(dtgServices.Item...) it only inserts 00.00 in the DB

```
 sqlCon.Open()
        dt = New DataTable
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO `custsrv`(`custName`, `mechFName`,`mechLName`, `jobSrv`, `jobPrice`) " &
                                  "  VALUES (@custName,@mechFName,@mechLName,@jobSrv,@jobPrice)", sqlCon)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custName", res_id.Text)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mechFName", txtMechFn.Text)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mechLName", txtMechLn.Text)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobsrv", txtService.Text)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobPrice", dtgServices.Item(2, i).Value)
        da.Fill(dt)
```

And the structure of my Datagridview is this

```
 connect_DB()
        dt = New DataTable
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT  m.mechfirstname as 'First Name',m.mechLastName as 'Last Name', " &
                                  "s.mechPosition as 'Position', j.jobPrice as 'Price' FROM mechanicprofile m " &
                                  "JOIN mechanicdeployment s ON s.mechid=m.mechID JOIN jobprofile j ON j.jobName=s.mechPosition ", sqlCon)
        da.Fill(dt)
        disconnect_DB()
        dtgServices.DataSource = dt`
```

Comment: please explain the structure of your dgv

Comment: What do you mean, the backend?

Comment: How do you want use to know what item to get if we don't know how `dtgServices` is structured or what it represents.